# Callback not executing inside another callback

Tags: react-native

I have a callback that I passed to this component named raiseKeyboard.  I want it to execute when the keyboard shows.

In this code, the callback does not execute at location ****1**** but executes successfully at location ****2****.

```
class AlbumCreateView extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this)
        this._keyboardDidShow = this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this)
      }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow () {
    this.props.raiseKeyboard //****1****
  }

  _keyboardDidHide () {
    //alert('Keyboard Hidden');
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.flatList}>
        <View style={styles.albumButton}>
          <Text onPress={this.props.raiseKeyboard}> //****2****
            raise modal
          </Text>
        </View>
        <TextInput onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
          placeholder='testing'
          keyboardType='default'
        />

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to actually execute the function?

```
_keyboardDidShow () {
    this.props.raiseKeyboard() //****1****
  }
```

Note: Missing the () at the end

Comment: You're right! This was driving me crazy.  Thank you!

Comment: Great! FYI, the reason it is working in the **2** is because you added it like this {function}. Making this {() => function} wouldn't work. Cheers